# Java Swing: ATM_Interface Key Events Not Detected After Initializing Authentification Class

Tags: java, swing

I'm building an ATM simulator and i want the PIN code to be verifyed when the ENTER key is pressed. However, i'm encountering an issue with key events not being detected in the ATM_Interface class after initializing the Authentication class. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       ATM_Interface atm=new ATM_Interface();
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
       frame.setLayout(null);
       frame.add(atm);
       frame.pack();
}
}
```

```
public class ATM_Interface extends JPanel {
  static String Status="";
  
   public ATM_Interface(){

  
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    this.setBackground(Color.blue);
    this.setBounds(115,67,340,340);
    this.addKeyListener(new keyAdapter());
    this.setFocusable(true);
    Authentication auth = new Authentication();  
    this.requestFocusInWindow();
              
   }


  
   class keyAdapter extends KeyAdapter{
         @Override
        public void     keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
           switch(Status){
            case "authentication":
            break;
            default:
            add(auth);
            Status="authentication";
            
          }
         System.out.println("test");
         }

       
               

         
   }
  
 }
```

```
public class Authentication extends  JPanel {        
    JTextField input = new  JTextField();
   public Authentication(){
        input.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
        this.add(input);

   }
   public boolean getAcces(){
     if(input.getText().equals("0234")){
          return true;
     }
     else return false;
   }
   
}
```

In this code, the ATM_Interface JPanel is supposed to capture key events using a KeyAdapter. However, after initializing the Authentification class and adding it as a child component to ATM_Interface, the key events are not being detected in the ATM_Interface JPanel.

I've already tried setting focus to the ATM_Interface panel using requestFocusInWindow() and setFocusable(), but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.
How can I ensure that key events are detected in the ATM_Interface JPanel? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have a focus related issue which is fixed by making use of the [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/misc/keybinding.html) API

Comment: Lots of things here but probably the most important is: [don't use null layouts](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing) I'm not too keen on the "auth when you've finished" typing approach (and if you're *going* to do that, it would be better to use a `DocumentListener`). It would be better to have a normal explicit "press button when done" approach, or better still, [use a `CardLayout`](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/64-java-login-with-cardlayout)

Comment: @MadProgrammer 
I've tried adding the following lines to my code:
```java
this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "verifyAction");  
this.getActionMap().put("verifyAction", new VerifyAction());
```
However, I'm still experiencing the same problem.
I'm new to Java, so I may have screwed it up.

Comment: I'm afraid that typing into a text field and then hitting enter is not standard enough an interface action, at least not without explicit instruction to do so. It therefore violates [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

Comment: @OussamaMahjour Consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: Just going to point out that doing this `Authentication auth = new Authentication(); ` in the constructor and then doing this `add(auth);` in the key event leads me to think you have a `NullPointerException`

Comment: @g00se
I'm simulating an ATM interface, which generally verifies your PIN code automatically after you enter the 4 digits. I wanted to test it first by pressing 'enter', so I got curious why it didn't work (for future reference).

Comment: Oh, OK. Yes that makes more sense. So - `DocumentListener` maybe

Comment: Also remember, `JTextField` supports `ActionListener` which will get triggered if you press [Enter] on most platforms

Comment: @MadProgrammer   i removed the "add(auth)"but it didn't work

Comment: @OussamaMahjour Please, provide a [mcve] in order to provide more context

Comment: @MadProgrammer I edited the question, is that enough ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the PIN code to be verifyed when the ENTER key is pressed

The simple answer is to use a `ActionListener` which will be called when the user "actions" the text field (ie, in most cases, presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key while the field is focused)

## A Minimal, Reproducible Example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField pinField;

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            pinField = new JTextField(4);
            add(pinField);

            pinField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String pinText = pinField.getText();
                    try {
                        int pinValue = Integer.parseInt(pinText);
                        if (pinValue != 1234) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Invalid PIN", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        } else {
                            // Now I'd use an observer here to notify interested
                            // parties that the pin was validated
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Invalid PIN", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

See:

- [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/components/textfield.html)
- [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/events/actionlistener.html)

for more details.

I would also suggest having a look at [Implementing a Document Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/components/generaltext.html#filter) if you're interested in limiting what the user can input into the text field (ie real time validation).  This would also allow you to "automatically" validate the PIN once it reaches the desired number of digits.

You should also take the time to learn and use the available [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/layout/index.html), that's just going to save you so much time and head aches.

Comment: Thank you so much . I appreciate your help and the clarity you provided.

Comment: Yes - *except* - you specifically said earlier that you wanted to have it authenticate as soon as the user has typed in the PIN (which is of course why you were using a `KeyAdapter`). Nothing about using the Enter key (which of course makes the problem trivial [though probably not for the user, for reasons I mentioned above])

Comment: @g00se *"and i want the PIN code to be verifyed when the ENTER key is pressed"* and they did say they would like to eventually auto valid, but they want to get it working with the enter key key.  Of the two approaches, this is the simpler, which might be a better place for the OP to start from - IMHO

Comment: *@g00se I'm simulating an ATM interface, which generally verifies your PIN code automatically after you enter the 4 digits. I wanted to test it first by pressing 'enter'*

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do it for you. See the Javadoc for [`DocumentListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html#changedUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent))

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;

public class Authentication extends JPanel implements DocumentListener {
    JTextField input = new JTextField();

    public Authentication() {
        input.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
        input.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
        this.add(input);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        if (getAccess()) {
            doOnAccess();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        if (getAccess()) {
            doOnAccess();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        if (getAccess()) {
            doOnAccess();
        }
    }

    private void doOnAccess() {
        System.out.println("Yes, we're in!");
    }

    public boolean getAccess() {
        return (input.getText().equals("0234"));
    }

}
```

Comment: I used a different approach but got the same results. However, as I mentioned earlier, I was wondering if the "enter method" had a solution. Nonetheless, I appreciate the help.